# VB.net staggerred array of different types

Tags: arrays, vb.net, dictionary

I'm creating a Windows application in VB.NET in which needs to store a decent amount of associative information about different applications. I'm trying to find out what the best way to store this data.

After doing some research the best solution that I have found is to use arrays of objects, or dictionaries of objects.

Here is my data structure that needs to be stored:

```
var Info[AppID]['AppName']-> String (returns the app name as String)
               ['Exes'] -> Array of Strings
               ['RegKeys'] -> Array of Strings
               ['Versions'][VersionID]['PCID'] -> String
                                      ['Date'] -> DateTime
                                      ['Size'] -> Integer
```

The keys without quotes are dynamic and represent the actual AppID/VersionID, the keys in quotes are static (so the 2nd key will always have 'AppName' 'Exes' etc.

So for example:

```
Info[123ab]['Name'] = 'Internet Exploder'
           ['Exes'] = {'iexplore.exe', 'whatever.exe'}
           ['RegKeys'] = {'hkey/local machine .....'}
           ['Versions'][1]['PCID'] = 'My Desktop'
                          ['Date'] = Jan 1 1960
                          ['Size'] = 9001
```

would be declared and set up as

```
    Dim appinfo As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
    Dim Lv2 As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)

    Dim Exes As New List(Of String)(New String() {"iexplorer.exe", "whatever.exe"})
    Dim RegKeys As New List(Of String)(New String() {"blah"})
    Dim Directories As New List(Of String)(New String() {"c:\program files\internet explorer"})
    Dim Name As String = "Internet Exploder"
    Dim Versions As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
    Dim VersionsLv2 As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)

    Dim VersionID As String = "1"
    Dim PCID As String = "My Desktop"
    Dim TheDate As Date = Now
    Dim Size As Integer = 9001

    VersionsLv2.Add("PCID", PCID)
    VersionsLv2.Add("Date", TheDate)
    VersionsLv2.Add("Size", Size)

    Versions.Add("VersionID", VersionsLv2)

    Lv2.Add("Name", Name)
    Lv2.Add("RegKeys", RegKeys)
    Lv2.Add("Directories", Directories)
    Lv2.Add("Versions", Versions)

    appinfo.Add("abc12", Lv2)
```

I'm just wondering if anyone knows any better way to do this? I kind of hate having to work from the top of the tree down in order to initialize the variable, but this seems to work ok.

Thank you very much for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you should be defining two types to begin with, e.g.

```
Class App

    Private ReadOnly _exes As New List(Of String)
    Private ReadOnly _regKeys As New List(Of String)
    Private ReadOnly _versions As New List(Of Version)

    Public Property AppId() As String
    Public Property AppName() As String

    Public ReadOnly Property Exes() As List(Of String)
        Get
            Return _exes
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property RegKeys() As List(Of String)
        Get
            Return _regKeys
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Versions() As List(Of Version)
        Get
            Return _versions
        End Get
    End Property

End Class

Class Version

    Public Property VersionId() As String
    Public Property PcId() As String
    Public Property [Date]() As Date
    Public Property Size() As Integer

End Class
```

In that example, the `Version` objects are stored in an `App` object in a simple collection and you would get them by index and use LINQ to get one by ID.  If you wanted, you could make the `Versions` property a `Dictionary` instead.  You could then create an array, `List` or `Dictionary` to store your `App` objects.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. It looks very appealing. I haven't spent too much time with vb.NET and have seen that you can define your own type with classes, but haven't been able to completely understand. I'll go back to the documentation on that one, but off hand - is there a particular reason why only the 3 Lists are in "public App() " and not the other properties? Isn't having those in an array redundant? Or am I understanding this incorrectly?

Comment: It is uncommon to have a read/write property exposing an array.  It is then possible for the existing array to be replaced from outside with a new one.  Usually a read-only property exposes a collection, so that items can be added and removed but the collection itself cannot be replaced.  There are many examples in the Framework itself, e.g. `ListBox.Items` and many more.  In my code above, the `App` constructor is used to create the empty collections when the `App` object itself is created.  The other properties don't need any initialisation so they are not referenced in the constructor.

Comment: @tinstaafl, good point and done.  I'm not sure why I did that in the first place.  The new code is slightly different in structure because of the differing syntax but functionally equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information. I noticed that your original answer was in C#, that didn't really faze me, but seeing the VB answer and it's syntax is definitely even more helpful. I will be implementing your suggestions. :)